# Laravel show ID of belongsto relationship

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.5 I have set up a belongs to relationship in my users model like this...

```
public function subscription() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Subscription');
}
```

In my blade template I can do this...

```
<td>{{$user->subscription}}</td>
```

Which returns...

```
{"id":2,"created_at":"2018-01-25"}
```

I am trying to return just the ID by doing this...

```
<td>{{$user->subscription->id}}</td>
```

But it is giving me an error 'Trying to get property of non-object '

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In your Subscription model have you set the relationship to hasOne?

Comment: Well I guess it's one of Laravel's own magic what happens here. Unfortunately they are not following a regular semantic versioning so anything non-backward compatible change could happened after 5.4 where this should've worked. Generally I would not recommend using this kind of chaining  (mostly the lazy loading stuff as it could end up in an error and inside the template you cannot catch it at all, but render a default 500 page) in templates but create the data structure in your code and then you could simply access them like {{$subscriptionId}}.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this by accessing the array item instead like this..

```
<td>{{$user->subscription['id']}}</td>
```

Comment: If `$user->subscription->id` doesn't work, but `$user->subscription['id']` does, there is something wrong in your code somewhere. The first example very much should work and does work in my L5.5 projects with `belongsTo` relationship.